# Why i am getting error on this code implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specifications ( mixing versions can lead to runtime crash). Found versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0.

I am getting this error while placing banner ads when I use this dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
```

Please look at the image and codes I provided and please help me.
I am currently using 3.1.2 android studio version.

these are the all codes.
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rbtcomedy.maharashtraresult"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.0.2'
}
```

Image link-https://drive.google.com/open?id=19WhSgZ2aTz_kZsFYeEVtejvAGBnPHJ0S

Answer (score 0):

The library defined with this dependency `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'` containts library of version  26.1.0, and you defined 27.1.1. So there are two same libs with different versions, you can fix this by excluding old one:  `exclude group: 'com.android.support'`

Answer (score 0):

Exlcude support library from espresso-Core as follows:

```
 androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
 }
```